# colorControlNormal not working on AppCompat.Dialog for lollipop devices

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-styles

I have created a custom datepicker dialog which extends a

`Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert`

I have created a style for this both in values/styles.xml and v21/styles.xml...

The code for the style is I created ::

```
<style name="MyDatePickerDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/accounts_darkgray_text</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/graph_rod_red</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

[image: My custom date picker]

Using colorControlNormal in v21 and above I am able to change the blue divider colors, but in lollipop and pre-lollipop devices, whatever I mention in the colorControlNormal , it does not seem to accept at all.

How can I change the divider colors, for 21 and < 21 android devices??

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the problem and thought would share the answer if this helps someone else.

I used the reflection technique to get hold of the "dividers" and change the color of it from code-behind.

```
LinearLayout llFirst = (LinearLayout) datePicker.getChildAt(0);
LinearLayout llSecond = (LinearLayout) llFirst.getChildAt(0);

for (int i = 0; i < llSecond.getChildCount(); i++) {

    // Numberpickers in llSecond
    NumberPicker picker = (NumberPicker) llSecond.getChildAt(i); 
    Field[] pickerFields = NumberPicker.class.getDeclaredFields();

    for (Field pf : pickerFields) {

        if (pf.getName().equals("mSelectionDivider")) {

            pf.setAccessible(true);

            try {
                ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(mActivity.getResources()
                      .getColor(R.color.date_picker_divider));
                pf.set(picker,colorDrawable);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException | Resources.NotFoundException 
                      | IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            break;
        }
    }
}
```